# Android's NavDeepLinkBuilder does not have option to not clear the task

Tags: android, graph, hyperlink, navigation

As stated in the documentation below, the NavDeepLinkBuilder will clear the task. But what if I don't want it to be cleared? Especially when my App is already in the foreground. It is a bad experience for the user!
I have "singleTop" for my activity enabled.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavDeepLinkBuilder

When this deep link is triggered:

The task is cleared.

Comment: Why is having a consistent back stack when your deep link is opened a bad experience for users? Can you explain your app's setup, what back stack you have prior to the deep link, what back stack you expect after your deep link, and your navigation graph?

Comment: Having a consistent back stack is not a bad experience. Consider a messenger application. I am in the Home page of my App with list of chats (start destination) and a message is received with notification having the deep link. Now, when the user taps on the notification, I don't want my activity to be recreated (with a splash screen) and then show the incoming chat (as the App was already in foreground). I expect the deep link to build on top of the existing destinations, if already present and it is building a similar path. This scenario is fine when the App is not in foreground.

Comment: We solved the backstack issue by introducing nested navigation graphs but we still have the issue where the launch screen is shown before the app is started because the activity is recreated

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround here. I will always use Deep Link to my main activity with parameters to indicate which destination the User has to be taken to.
The destination will have a global action that will be used in case of the Deep Link.

Comment: Could you please add a codebase sample for this answer?